# Why is Aluminium and Magnesium used as anodes in X-ray sources for X-ray Photoelectron Spectroscopy (XPS)?

Tags: spectroscopy, photoelectric-effect, x-rays

Is there any particular reason for using Al/Mg Kα rays in X-Ray Photoelectron Spectroscopy?

I read that the energy of the X-Rays produced by taking these elements as the anode materials can decrease the energy of X-Rays. I would like an elaboration on this particular statement.

Moreover, does the Full Width Half Maxima (FWHM) have any role to play in this scenario?

Comment: Why the close votes? It's a perfectly good experimental physics question. I'm curious what the answer is.

Comment: My best guess is because these are the easiest to work with metals with low x-ray emission energy. The other choices are Li, Be and Na. For all I know Lithium and Sodium probably have an awfully high vapor pressure in vacuum and low melting point and would contaminate the entire vacuum system (that happened to a fellow student of mine once). Making clean, oxide free surfaces is also very hard. Beryllium has a very low "x-ray" energy of 110eV. Leaves Mg and Al in the low keV range. I might be completely wrong, so I am not going to make that an answer.

Comment: Two (related) factors come to mind immediately. One, you want to be surface sensitive at the sample so lower energy x-rays are better. Two, since the UHV chamber is mostly steel, low energy x-rays don’t get out of it so potential radiation exposure is minimized.

Comment: @JonCuster At that energy, it doesn't matter what the chamber is made of.

Comment: Sure, although the windows count too. Both sapphire and quartz windows will be sufficient for Al and Mg K-alpha.

Comment: @JonCuster I've never seen sapphire or quartz thin enough for <2 keV. I've used very thin Be and SiN, but you can't make a chamber with foil.

Comment: @JonCuster Could you please elaborate on why lower energy X-rays are better for surface sensitivity? I thought about it, but I am not able to reach a definite answer.

Comment: @JitinSathishKumar - two considerations: (1) how far into the material will the x-ray penetrate? (2) through how much material will a photoelectron travel without scattering?